# How is the syntax of type systems read?

Tags: haskell, semantics, type-systems

I have the following types for functions:

```
Quad = square · square
Square :: Integer -> Integer (So this function takes an integer as an input and outputs an integer)

The operator · is used in the definition of quad with type:

(·) :: (Integer -> Integer) -> (Integer -> Integer) -> Integer -> Integer
```

I am unsure how the above is read as and the meaning behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double `::` suggests this is Haskell, but the general principles are the same across all ML inspired languages (most, and type theoretic convention, is to use a single `:`).

The `::` symbol says that its left hand side has the type of its right hand side.  So

```
1 :: Integer
```

The `->` constructs a function type.

```
timesTwo :: Integer -> Integer
```

Further, `->` is right associative.

```
plus :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
```

says the function `plus` takes an integer and gives back a *function* which takes an integer and gives back an integer.  This is equivalent to taking two integers, but is technically different (and in a sense, simpler).  It is known as currying.

```
square :: Integer -> Integer
```

says that square takes an integer and returns an integer.

Often, in type theory and functional programming languages we make use of type variables, so

```
id :: forall a. a -> a
id x = x
```

says that *for any type `a`* id is a function from a value of that type to *another value of the same type*.  Your `.` operator makes more sense when it is given a *more general* type using variables

```
(·) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
f . g x = f (g (x))
```

is the function composition function.  It is a higher order function that takes two functions as arguments.  More formally, for any types `a`, `b`, and `c`, `(.)` is a function from a function from `b` to `c` *to a function* from `a` to `b` *to a function* from `a` to `c`.  The final function is just the [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) of the two argument functions.

You have specialized `.` to only work on Integers.  But, the idea is the same.  You take two functions from `Integer -> Integer` and an `Integer`, you apply the first function, and then apply the second function the the result.

`(.)` or `(+)` is just Haskell for "this is an infix operator but I want to talk about it right now in prefix form."

So, `Quad` is just a function from `Integer -> Integer` that calls square on its argument, and then calls square again on the result.  It would be the same as

```
quad x = square (square x)
```

(haskell is case sensitive, and functions must start with lowercase letters)